# Getting src from element using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get the src of an element as a string.

I used `find_element_by_xpath()` to find the element. I'm able to use `element.get_attribute("class")` to get the class but unable to get the `src` this way.

A snippet of my code:

```
image = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="irc_cc"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img')
print(image.get_attribute("class"))
print(image.get_attribute("src"))
```

Here is the result my terminal:

`irc_mi 
 None`

This is what the element in chrome inspect element looks like:

[image: element]

Comment: I believe you might have more than one items matching with that xpath and the first matching item might not have the `src`. Can you quickly check `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="irc_cc"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img')))` to make sure you have only one item with that matching xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you were close. To extract the **src** *attribute* as the element is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.irc_mi[alt='Image result for snowman']"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='irc_mi' and @alt='Image result for snowman']"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Using your method, I've ran into another problem. It possible to call EC.visibility_of_element_located without the @alt parameter? Can I get the src by just using the class name?

Comment: I just used the absolute xpath instead of "//img[@class='irc_mi' and @alt='Image result for snowman']" and it works now. Great!